# How to sort Strings in C#

Tags: c#, string

I have to sort an array of strings. How can I do that, if:

1. They must be placed in order of string length.
2. If lengths are equal, the must be placed alphabetically.

Is there any simple to do that ?

Comment: What code do you have so far?

Comment: Well you can call `Array.Sort` and pass in an `IComparer<string>` or a `Comparison<string>`... or you could use LINQ... have you tried anything yet? What happened?

Comment: take a look at this   http://www.dotnetperls.com/sort

Comment: Thanks for the answers, but it need the solution without using LINQ, that's why I created question. I should have mentioned that before.

Comment: @Imugi, so you should write your own way of sorting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the traditional way in C# ...

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    List<string> list = new List<string>();
    list.Add("1991728819928891");
    list.Add("0991728819928891");
    list.Add("3991728819928891");
    list.Add("2991728819928891");
    list.Add("Hello");
    list.Add("World");
    list.Add("StackOverflow");
    list.Sort(
        delegate (string a, string b) {
            int result = a.Length.CompareTo(b.Length);
            if (result == 0 )
                result = a.CompareTo(b);
            return result;
        }
    );

    Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", list.ToArray()));
}
```

Sample Output:

```
Hello
World
StackOverflow
0991728819928891
1991728819928891
2991728819928891
3991728819928891
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with LINQ in the following way:

```
string[] arr = new[] { "aa", "b", "a" , "c",  "ac" };
var res = arr.OrderBy(x => x.Length).ThenBy(x => x).ToArray();
```

Another way is to use `Array.Sort` with custom `IComparer` implementation.